# Although I used the GridSearchCV, I get a lower score than the model I have never used any params. What could be the reason?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

When trying to do model tunning, it gave me a bad score than before.
Here is my code:

**Before Tunning**

```
rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = rf_model.predict(X_test)

rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
rmse
```

it gave : 344.73852779396566

But when I try to do with **GridSearchCV**,

```
rf_params = {"max_depth":[5,8,10],
             "max_features":[2,5,10],
             "n_estimators":[200,500,100,2000],
             "min_samples_split":[2,10,80]}

rf_cv = GridSearchCV(rf_model, rf_params, 
            cv = 10, verbose = 2, n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train, y_train)
rf_cv.best_params_
```

it gave me the best parameters like:

```
{'max_depth': 8,
 'max_features': 2,
 'min_samples_split': 2,
 'n_estimators': 200}
```

and then I trained the model again with these parameters:

**Tunning**

```
rf_tunned = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=8,
                                  max_features = 2,
                                  min_samples_split = 2,
                                  n_estimators = 200).fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = rf_tunned.predict(X_test)

rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
rmse
```

it gave me rmse: 350.14634045283685

What is the reason of this situation? Don't we use the model tunning for better results?

Comment: How many total features in your dataset?

Comment: df.shape is (263, 20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to keep in mind:

1. By simply running `RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)`, you revert to the default values of all arguments (except `random_state`) as described in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html).
2. Grid search is not "magic" or all-encompassing; it will only test the parameter combinations in the range you have specify.

Checking the default values of the arguments in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html), turns out that your `RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)` run is actually equivalent to the following parameter settings:

```
{'max_depth': None,  # full tree depth
 'max_features': 20, # all features (default)
 'min_samples_split': 2,
 'n_estimators': 100}
```

This combination is not included in the parameter ranges you specified for grid search, so it was never *tried*. Hence, it is not strange that it actually gives a better error than your *specific* grid search.